# Changing textbox value should update hidden field

Tags: asp.net

I have a hidden field which i want to update everytime when my textbox value is changed. It doesnt matter whether i am changing value at server side or client side when the textbox value changes hidden field should be updated. I have used onchange event of textbox but it does not work as i am changing values of textbox programatically. How can i do this?

Comment: you can use jQuery to achieve this, do you know how to use it ? if yes I will post the full code that you will need to put in order to make it work.

Comment: It would be nice if you can send me the code.  Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it separately.

In the code behind you need to add in the `TextBox_TextChanged` event

`HiddenField.Value = TextBox.Text`

And in the client side you need to add the onchange event like `onchange="javascript:updateHiddenField();"` and then do something like:

```
function updateHiddenField() {
  document.getElementById('HiddenFieldClientID').value = document.getElementById('TextBoxClientID').value  
}
```

Beware that if you use MasterPages or databinding controls like repeaters/gridviews etc then the ClientID won't be the same as the ID.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden field defined thusly:

```
<input type="hidden" id="BillMeFormReferred" name="referred" />
```

needs to pull the value of a textbox that is contained by a different form - that is, the hidden field is on a form being submitted - the text box sits in a different form _not_being_submitted.

jQuery is able to accomplish this via a button coded thusly:

```
<input type="button" value="Bill Me" id="BillMe"
  onclick="$('#BillMeFormReferred').val(   // the setter form of .val
                   $('#tbReferred').val() //  references the remote field ID
                   ); $('#BillMeForm').submit();" />
```